# Use a file with row numbers to delete rows in a separate file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file containing row numbers (I'll call it recordsToRemove) that need to be removed from a separate, very large file. There are quite a few rows to remove (approximately 10,000), so typing each row number to remove is not really an option. I have searched quite a bit and have yet to find a unix or similar solution to do this.

Snippet of recordsToRemove:

```
5
7
9
13
18
26
28
29
30
36
...
596687
596688
596689
596690
596691
596697
596700
596706
596709
596716
```

The file that I need to remove files from is a large file that is space delimited with 100,000+ columns:

```
10 -10 10 -10 10 10 10 10 10 -10 -10 0 0 -10 0 0 10 10 -10 -10 
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 10 -10 -10 10 -10 -10 10 -10 10 10 -10 -10 10 -10 -10 
10 10 -10 10 -10 -10 -10 10 10 -10 -10 0 0 -10 0 0 10 0 0 -10 
10 10 -10 10 -10 -10 -10 10 10 0 -10 0 0 -10 0 0 10 0 0 -10 
10 10 -10 10 -10 -10 -10 0 0 0 0 10 -10 10 10 -10 -10 10 10 10 
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 10 -10 -10 10 -10 0 10 0 0 
0 10 -10 10 -10 -10 -10 10 10 -10 -10 10 -10 -10 10 -10 10 10 -10 -10 
10 -10 10 -10 10 10 10 0 0 0 -10 0 0 -10 0 0 0 10 0 0 
...
```

I Would greatly appreciate any suggestions for how to accomplish this!

Comment: You are trying to remove lines or columns from the data file?

Comment: I'm trying to remove lines (rows) from the data file

Comment: pls define "very large", what is the size of the file? Do you have enough spaces on your hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

just give this a try, if it works there:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{d[0+$0]=7;next}!d[FNR]' recordsToRemove  bigFile > Result.txt
```

save the rowNo. to be deleted in memory as hashtable entries. 10k entries are nothing for your memory I think.

Then check each row No. in that bigfile, if it exists in the hashtable. the `get()` method of a hashtable would be considered as `O(1)`, performance should not be a problem. Just give it a try on your real data.

Comment: Thanks so much! This does just what I needed. If you have a chance and don't mind, could you explain the details of it?  No problem if not - just a newbie trying to learn =)

Comment: @klpgaddis I 've explained how does the one-liner work under the code block.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sticking a `d` on the end of each line of `recordsToRemove` and then run `sed -f recordsToRemove largeFile`.